# How to create next and Previous button inside Preference Page?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, project

I have created Eclipse Plugin project. I have added new Option"Test Tool" inside the Preference Page. I have disable default Restore Default and Apply button.I need to add the Previous and next button inside the prefernce page.
Do anyone can help me?

I have tried by writing new Class which extends MultiPageEditorPart and implemented nextButton and backButton. But now how to add that class in preference page? How to add inside createFieldEditors to show button in the existing page?

Comment: It is extremely rare to have Next and Previous in a preference page. Most pages that want more data than can fit on one page use CTabFolder to have tabs, or use multiple preferences pages in tree structure.

Comment: But my project requirement is to created multiple preference pages. There should be next button in every preference page which will save current page data and move it to next configuration input page. Do you have an idea how to implement it?

Comment: That really doesn't sound like something that should be a preference page. [edit] your question and explain in more detail why you think you need this. Of the many preference pages in my Eclipse install there is not a single one with Next/Previous.

Comment: Ok i mean to say inside a prefernce page i want to create back and next button where next button will take to new screen page where it required some user input. I don't want to open new window when clicking on next button. New configuration page should come in the same preference page.